# Polymer input label using content

Tags: html, data-binding, polymer

I have the following code.

```
<template if="{{editing}}">
  <div hidden="hidden" class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h2"></content>
  </div>
  <paper-input label="New Name"></paper-input>
</template>
```

I want to set the `label` on the `paper-input` to be the content selected by `h2`.

So the hidden elements here would contain `<h2> the thing I'm editing </h2>`. I want the text "the thing I'm editing" to be the label for the `paper-input` element.

Comment: What's the significance of including those `<content>` elements in a `<div hidden>`? Is the fact that they're hidden something that's core to your question (i.e. you can get it to work normally, just not when it's hidden) or is it just an unrelated detail? If it's unrelated, could you simplify your question by excluded that extra detail?

Comment: I'm still new to polymer, and when I remove the hidden element, I get an `<h2>` shoved into the dom. To hide it, I'm just putting it in a hidden `<div>`. It really feels like the wrong way to do it, but that's a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is use `getDistributedNodes()` on the content, extra the `h2.textContent` and data bind the paper-input's label to that value:

```
<div hidden>
  <content id="c" select="h2"></content>
</div>
<paper-input label="{{label}}"></paper-input>

..

Polymer('my-element', {
  attached: function() {
    this.label = this.$.c.getDistributedNodes()[0].textContent;
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/tiwedacepimi/1/edit

Note: I'm using the `hidden` attribute which hides the nodes projected at the `<content>`. Really the only reason to use `<content>` here is to ensure you're getting just the nodes your element expects. `<content>` insertion points are purely for rendering nodes in user world into the shadow dom world. However, you're hiding them :)